# azure storage emulator 1603

Tags: azure, installation, storage

Can't install azure storage emulator, any version. I've tried all the tricks to get it working, no luck. Been googling for two days, can't seem to solve this one. My last clue was error 1603 but I can't pinpoint the problem.

Here's the full log: [Log](http://pastebin.com/Pm9HkPwi)

UPDATE: Here's the partial relevant log.

```
CAQuietExec:  Windows Azure Storage Emulator 3.4.0.0 command line tool
CAQuietExec:  Error: Cannot create database.
CAQuietExec:  Error 0xfffffff3: Command line returned an error.
CAQuietExec:  Error 0xfffffff3: CAQuietExec Failed
CustomAction RunInitialize returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 18:28:39: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.
Action ended 18:28:39: INSTALL. Return value 3.
Property(S): UpgradeCode = {CF5CD495-AEDE-42DA-B7CF-A70D398D4E6A}
Property(S): RunInitialize = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\WAStorageEmulator.exe" init -forcecreate -autodetect
Property(S): DOTNET4FULL = 4.5.51650
Property(S): LOCALDB11INSTALLED = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\LocalDB\Binn\SqlUserInstance.dll
Property(S): LOCALDB12INSTALLED = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\LocalDB\Binn\SqlUserInstance.dll
Property(S): TARGETDIR = C:\
Property(S): StorageEmulatorMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Azure\Storage Emulator\
Property(S): STORAGEEMUDIR = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\
Property(S): WixUIRMOption = UseRM
Property(S): ALLUSERS = 1
Property(S): ARPNOMODIFY = 1
Property(S): REINSTALLMODE = amus
Property(S): AzureMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Azure\
Property(S): ProgramMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\
Property(S): AZUREDIR = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\
Property(S): MICROSOFTSDKSDIR = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\
Property(S): ProgramFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\
Property(S): SourceDir = C:\Users\mgeric\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsAzureStorageEmulator.3.4\020A162F19165C248D599F12BEFCA3CF77A881BF\
Property(S): MSIRMSHUTDOWN = 1
Property(S): WIXUI_INSTALLDIR = INSTALLDIR
Property(S): ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT = 1
Property(S): DefaultUIFont = WixUI_Font_Normal
Property(S): WixUI_Mode = Minimal
Property(S): Manufacturer = Microsoft Corporation
Property(S): ProductCode = {D1CE3A61-C902-4065-86BE-2007DB996CC5}
Property(S): ProductLanguage = 1033
Property(S): ProductName = Windows Azure Storage Emulator - v3.4
Property(S): ProductVersion = 3.4.6848.0
Property(S): ErrorDialog = ErrorDlg
Property(S): SecureCustomProperties = NEWERVERSIONDETECTED;OLDEMULATORPACKAGEDETECTED;OLDERVERSIONDETECTED
Property(S): WixPdbPath = o:\bttemp\291696\obj.amd64fre\services\xstore\rdpackages\storageemulatorpackage\objfre\amd64\en-us\WindowsAzureStorageEmulator.wixpdb
Property(S): MsiLogFileLocation = C:\Users\mgeric\AppData\Local\Temp\WindowsAzureStorageEmulator.txt
Property(S): PackageCode = {D5D2BCEC-CE8A-451B-8864-29D94AB03AA0}
Property(S): ProductState = -1
Property(S): PackagecodeChanging = 1
Property(S): REBOOT = ReallySuppress
Property(S): CURRENTDIRECTORY = C:\Windows\SysWOW64
Property(S): CLIENTUILEVEL = 3
Property(S): CLIENTPROCESSID = 7564
Property(S): VersionDatabase = 200
Property(S): VersionMsi = 5.00
Property(S): VersionNT = 603
Property(S): VersionNT64 = 603
Property(S): WindowsBuild = 9600
Property(S): ServicePackLevel = 0
Property(S): ServicePackLevelMinor = 0
Property(S): MsiNTProductType = 1
Property(S): WindowsFolder = C:\Windows\
Property(S): WindowsVolume = C:\
Property(S): System64Folder = C:\Windows\system32\
Property(S): SystemFolder = C:\Windows\SysWOW64\
Property(S): RemoteAdminTS = 1
Property(S): TempFolder = C:\Users\mgeric\AppData\Local\Temp\
Property(S): CommonFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\
Property(S): ProgramFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\
Property(S): CommonFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\Common Files\
Property(S): AppDataFolder = C:\Users\mgeric\AppData\Roaming\
Property(S): FavoritesFolder = C:\Users\mgeric\Favorites\
Property(S): NetHoodFolder = C:\Users\mgeric\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\
Property(S): PersonalFolder = C:\Users\mgeric\Documents\
Property(S): PrintHoodFolder = C:\Users\mgeric\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts\
Property(S): RecentFolder = C:\Users\mgeric\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\
Property(S): SendToFolder = C:\Users\mgeric\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\
Property(S): TemplateFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Templates\
Property(S): CommonAppDataFolder = C:\ProgramData\
Property(S): LocalAppDataFolder = C:\Users\mgeric\AppData\Local\
Property(S): MyPicturesFolder = C:\Users\mgeric\Pictures\
Property(S): AdminToolsFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools\
Property(S): StartupFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\
Property(S): StartMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\
Property(S): DesktopFolder = C:\Users\Public\Desktop\
Property(S): FontsFolder = C:\Windows\Fonts\
Property(S): GPTSupport = 1
Property(S): OLEAdvtSupport = 1
Property(S): ShellAdvtSupport = 1
Property(S): MsiAMD64 = 6
Property(S): Msix64 = 6
Property(S): Intel = 6
Property(S): PhysicalMemory = 16292
Property(S): VirtualMemory = 13843
Property(S): AdminUser = 1
Property(S): MsiTrueAdminUser = 1
Property(S): LogonUser = mgeric
Property(S): UserSID = S-1-5-21-857309233-1194579618-3398700826-1001
Property(S): UserLanguageID = 1050
Property(S): ComputerName = MGERIC-MBP
Property(S): SystemLanguageID = 1050
Property(S): ScreenX = 1024
Property(S): ScreenY = 768
Property(S): CaptionHeight = 44
Property(S): BorderTop = 1
Property(S): BorderSide = 1
Property(S): TextHeight = 16
Property(S): TextInternalLeading = 3
Property(S): ColorBits = 32
Property(S): TTCSupport = 1
Property(S): Time = 18:28:39
Property(S): Date = 23.4.2015.
Property(S): MsiNetAssemblySupport = 4.0.30319.33440
Property(S): MsiWin32AssemblySupport = 6.3.9600.17415
Property(S): RedirectedDllSupport = 2
Property(S): MsiRunningElevated = 1
Property(S): Privileged = 1
Property(S): USERNAME = mgeric
Property(S): DATABASE = C:\Windows\Installer\c96f7.msi
Property(S): OriginalDatabase = C:\Users\mgeric\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsAzureStorageEmulator.3.4\020A162F19165C248D599F12BEFCA3CF77A881BF\WindowsAzureStorageEmulator.msi
Property(S): UILevel = 2
Property(S): ACTION = INSTALL
Property(S): ROOTDRIVE = C:\
Property(S): CostingComplete = 1
Property(S): OutOfDiskSpace = 0
Property(S): OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0
Property(S): PrimaryVolumeSpaceAvailable = 0
Property(S): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRequired = 0
Property(S): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRemaining = 0
Property(S): INSTALLLEVEL = 1
Property(S): SOURCEDIR = C:\Users\mgeric\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsAzureStorageEmulator.3.4\020A162F19165C248D599F12BEFCA3CF77A881BF\
Property(S): SourcedirProduct = {D1CE3A61-C902-4065-86BE-2007DB996CC5}
Property(S): ProductToBeRegistered = 1
=== Logging stopped: 23.4.2015.  18:28:39 ===
MSI (s) (A8:6C) [18:28:39:431]: Product: Windows Azure Storage Emulator - v3.4 -- Installation failed.

MSI (s) (A8:6C) [18:28:39:431]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: Windows Azure Storage Emulator - v3.4. Product Version: 3.4.6848.0. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation. Installation success or error status: 1603.
```

Comment: Your log says `CAQuietExec:  Error: Cannot create database.
CAQuietExec:  Error 0xfffffff3: Command line returned an error.
CAQuietExec:  Error 0xfffffff3: CAQuietExec Failed`.

Comment: Thanks Isim, that's the error that gets output in the console widows as well, that much I know. But why is it happening? I tried at least a 100 solutions and none seems to work.

Comment: Well, do you have something like Sql Server Express installed? Do you have permission to create databases in there? Do you see any databases when run `sqllocaldb -i` from your command prompt?

Comment: I have a sql server 2014 installed and a SQLLocalDB obviously. It won't install use any of them, always the same error. What do you mean do I have permission? I'm running the installation elevated, it shouldn't require any special permission, right? When I run sqllocaldb info, I get three instances (v11.0, MSSQLLocalDB and one other) but I can't use any of them, always the same error. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try delete the existing `v11.0` instance, and then re-install azure storage emulator again. Not sure why you can't use any of the instances.

Comment: I've tried stoping, deleting, recreating, nothing seems to work. So, nothing special can be seen from the log?

Comment: After you deleted your `v11.0` instance, don't re-create the instance. Delete  `c:\users\<your_account>\WAStorageEmulatorDb30.mdf` and `c:\users\<your_account>\WAStorageEmulatorDb30_log.ldf`, and then re-attempt installing the storage emulator.

Comment: Hi Isim, I've tried that as well, I get the same message and those files in c:\users\<your_account> never get created.

Comment: Strange.. Can you add the content of your `c:\users\<your_account>\AppData\Local\DevelopmentStorage\DevelopmentStorage.<date>.config` file to your question? You should see a line that says `<SQLInstance>(localdb)\v11.0</SQLInstance>`. FWIW, try change it to `<SQLInstance>{MyComputerName}\SQLEXPRESS</SQLInstance>`. By default, the storage emulator uses Sql Server Express with the LocalDB execution mode.

Comment: It does show (localdb)\v11.0, I've tried changing it to my sql server instance (I don't have express, I have the full server), makes no difference. I've also tried to change the instance using the command line tool, no dice. I've tried all of this and nothing seems to work. I was hoping that maybe the log would tell something.

Comment: Assuming your user account does have administrative privilege to perform the installation, the only last thing I can think of is to open up the Windows Event Viewer or Application Logs to see if there are any relevant errors.

Comment: I'm running the installation elevated and my user is added to sql server logins, I've event assigned myself all of the roles. Still nothing. And I can't see anything in Event Viewer that would even indicate a problem.

Comment: Try it on another server to see if it works.

Comment: Unbelievable, the culprit for this mess was Astrill vpn client. If you have Astrill installed, there's no way of getting Storage emulator to work, I've confirmed this with several colleagues, we've found no way for the them to coexist on the same system. But as soon as you uninstall Astrill, Azure storage emulator magically starts functioning properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had Astrill client installed. It seems Astrill prevents Azure storage emulator from functioning properly. As soon as I removed Astrill (uninstalled), storage emulator started functioning properly again. Tried this several times and every time it was the same. I've also confirmed this with other colleagues. Astrill just won't play nice with Azure storage emulator.